# Blueimp/jQuery File Uploader не грузит файлы при использовании "красивых URL"

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, apache, fileupload

```
RewriteRule ^edit_storage/(.*)$ ./edit_storage.php?object_key=$1
```

Это то, как у меня сделан URL страницы.
Загвоздка в чем, если писать нормальный URL вида: `/edit_storage/12345678` - то нихрена не пашет, но если писать дичь: `/edit_storage?object_key=12345678` - то все нормально.

"Нихрена не пашет" в том смысле, что гуй загрузчика прогружается, но без уже залитых файлов. При попытке что либо загрузить ругается: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1`

С чем это может быть связанно? И как это лечить?

Answer (score 0):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1` ищите лишнюю < в файле ответа, бывает что вместо `<?php ?>` получается `<<?php ?>` и при выводе ответа вместо корректной строки JSON: `{"key":"value"}` возвращает некоректное `<{"key":"value"}`

Comment: Я не нашел ничего подобного, хотя и искал не сильно долго. У Blueimp есть только один php файл, UploadHandler.php, и в нем такого нет. В остальном одни .js'ы.

Проверял через Sublime Text 3 с помощью Ctrl+Shift+F "<<", ни в одном файле ничего не нашлось.